# Excel Macro/how to write macro to copy/paste rows from Workbook with 200 sheets to Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Workbook (named Peak) with 100 sheets (each Sheet starts with Sheet1 followed by a unique name, Sheet1AA), I want to copy one column from each Peak Sheet and paste into a new Workbook (named Table) using transpose, so the Table will have 100 rows of data from the Peak Workbook Sheets. Below is an example where two Sheets are copied and then pasted, with the second Sheet (Sheet1BB) pasted below the first Sheet (Sheet1AA) in the Table. I know I can record a macro as I do the copy/paste-transpose, but hoping there is a way to write a macro to do the copy/paste consecutively/in order from the Peak Workbook (Sheet1AA-Sheet1ZZ) to the Workbook Table to give 100 rows of data, with data from Sheet1AA the first row and Sheet1ZZ the last row in the Table.
Thank you

```
Windows("Peak.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1AA").Select
Range("O6:O150").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Table.xlsm").Activate
Range("E4:AB4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Windows("Peak.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1BB").Select
Range("O6:O150").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Table.xlsm").Activate
Range("E5:AB5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
Dim r As Long, sht As Worksheet

r = 4

For Each sht In Workbooks("Peak.xlsm").Worksheets
    sht.Range("O6:O150").Copy
    Workbooks("Table.xlsm").Sheets(1).Cells(r, "E").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    r = r + 1
Next sht
```

Comment: Do you mean to say r=r+1?

Comment: Hi Tim,Thanks for the help on this, right now I get a Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method with the following highlighted in Yellow: For Each sht In Windows("Peak.xlsm").Worksheets, Below is the macro                     Sub Macro3_TestPeak_to_Table_Auto()
'
' Macro3_TestPeak_to_Table_Auto Macro
'

'
   Dim r As Long

r = 4

For Each sht In Windows("Peak.xlsm").Worksheets
    sht.Range("O6:O150").Copy
    Workbooks("Table.xlsm").Sheets(1).Cells(r, "E").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    r = r = 1
Next sht
End Sub

Comment: Thanks Kerry, corrected it to r-r+1, but still get the same run-time error '438' for: Each sht In Windows("Peak.xlsm").Worksheets

Comment: Sorry - another edit "worksbooks" >> `WorkBooks`   That's what happens when I don't write code in the VB Editor...

Comment: when I hold the cursor over sht in the Yellow highlighted:  Each sht In Windows("Peak.xlsm").Worksheets, I get a little popup window with sht=Empty

Comment: Tim, THANK YOU!, when you mentioned sheet order (Sheets were out of order), I used a Workbook where the sheets were ordered, and then your first macro worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Since OP's need to maintain pasted data ordered by parent sheet name, here follows two possible codes:

---

**temporary helper column**

this approach

- inserts a (temporary) column right before column "E" where to store sheet names, while corresponding data are written from the next column to rigthwards.
- sorts the pasted range on sheet names in (temporary) column "E"
- deletes temporary column

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Sub Main()
      Dim iSht As Long
      Dim sht As Worksheet

      With Workbooks("Table.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
          .Columns("E").Insert '<--| insert temporary helper column
          For Each sht In Workbooks("Peak.xlsm").Worksheets '<--| loop through sheets
              sht.Range("O6:O150").Copy
              .Cells(4 + iSht, "E") = sht.Name '<--| write sheet name in temporary helper column
              .Cells(4 + iSht, "F").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True '<--| write data from the next colum rightwards
              iSht = iSht + 1
          Next sht

          With .Cells(4, "E").Resize(iSht, 146) '<--| consider temporary helper column cells containing sheet names
              .Sort key1:=.Cells(1, 1), order1:=xlAscending '<--| sort them
              .EntireColumn.Delete '<--| remove temporary helper column
          End With
      End With
  End Sub
  ```

---

**array with ordered sheet names**

this requires writing them down in a temporary sheet (in `ThisWorkbook`), sorting them and reading them back (see `Function GetSortedWsNames()`)

```
Sub Main2()
    Dim i As Long: i = 4
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim el As Variant

    Set wb = Workbooks("Peak.xlsm")
    With Workbooks("Table.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
       For Each el In GetSortedWsNames(wb)
           wb.Worksheets(el).Range("O6:O150").Copy
           .Cells(i, "E").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
           i = i + 1
       Next el
    End With
End Sub


Function GetSortedWsNames(wb As Workbook) As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iSht As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With wb
        For iSht = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
           ws.Cells(iSht, 1) = .Worksheets(iSht).Name
        Next iSht
    End With

    With ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(iSht - 1)
        .Sort key1:=ws.Cells(1, 1), order1:=xlAscending
        GetSortedWsNames = Application.Transpose(.Cells)
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, will look into these two macros too!

Comment: You are welcome. I actually already posted the 2nd one yesterday before you marked any answer as accepted. I found it quite weird you didn't consider it although it fully complied with ALL of your requests (copy&paste in order) while marked as accepted an answer that didn't....

Comment: Hi, 
Actually I did try your second longer macro but got an error, think it had something to do with the first end sub (I am not very experienced with VBA). Since the data I need to process are in sheets that are in order the first macro by Tim did the job. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: You are welcome, again. _"Since the data I need to process are in sheets that are in order "_: that was not what I got from your question narrative, hence my attempts at helping you with code that provided the (what I thought it was) desired sheet ordering